# Transferred iOS App and want to send push notifications using Auth Key

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have transferred an iOS app. It was using SSL certificates to send push notifications in Production. 
In the new developer program I would like to switch to using Auth Key.

The App ID has been transferred so it is part of the new developer program.

Can I send push notifications from the new developer program with the new Auth Key without making a new version of the app?